# Who to find out the Id of TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android

Look at the Title

I don't wont to make anything in the main.xml

Comment: What makes you think that `TimePickerDialogs` have IDs?

Answer (score 0):

As Mark said TimePickerDialog doesn´t have any id
you want to create a TimePickerDialog?, this is a basic example ::

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //***Create your TimePickerDialog!!!
        new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener, 12, 12, false).show();
    }

    private  TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Toast.makeText(GR_Comments.this, "my Time is :: " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }           
    };
```